Why is additivity not added to the Linear Programming formulation of a two-player zero-sum game?
The Linear Programming formulation of a two-player zero-sum game is generally written in a form something like...$$\max\limits_{\vec x} v \\ s.t.\ \ \ \forall j,\ v \leq \sum_{i = 1}^m a_{ij}x_i \\ \sum_{i = 1}^m x_i = 1 \\ \forall i,\ x_i \geq 0$$
The first line of constraints is just a way to make it a Linear Program.  The $x_i$'s are the probabilities assignable to each action in a mixed strategy, and the second and third lines of constraints can be thought of as telling the Linear Program that the $x_i$'s are probabilities rather than arbitrary variables.  However, there is a single probability axiom missing, additivity.
Why does the Linear Program need to be given the other two axioms to treat the $x_i$'s like probabilities, but not either countable additivity or finite additivity?

It is a finite probablility space with $m$ atoms, you just assign the probabilities to those $m$ atoms. Additivity in this context just means that if you take the subset of those atoms then its probability is the sum of the elements.
